# Error Unclosed quotation mark after the character string & window azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to run my SQL script in windows azure.I convert my query using `SQLAzureMW v3.9.9.1 Release Binary` and when I try to run the script I got error
`Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ...` in  converted sp.
My sp is fine in `MSSQL 2008`.

My sp before convert:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[EntryUpdate]

        @EntryID INT, 
        @Value NVARCHAR(100), 
        @Text NVARCHAR(150), 
        @CurrencyCode NVARCHAR(50),
        @DisplayLocale NVARCHAR(50),
        @Description NVARCHAR(500),
        @IsActive BIT,
        @UpdatedBy NVARCHAR(256),
        @Culture NVARCHAR(256)

    AS
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.Lists
            SET 
                [Value] = @Value,
                [Text] = @Text,         
                [CurrencyCode]=@CurrencyCode,
                [DisplayLocale]=@DisplayLocale,
                [Description] = @Description,
                [IsActive]=@IsActive,
                [UpdatedBy] = @UpdatedBy,   
                [UpdatedOn] = GETDATE()
            WHERE   [EntryID] = @EntryID AND Culture=@Culture
    END
```

After Convert with `SQLAzureMW v3.9.9.1 Release Binary` my sp looks:

```
--Other Procedure
' 
END
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[EntryUpdate]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
BEGIN
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[EntryUpdate]

    @EntryID INT, 
    @Value NVARCHAR(100), 
    @Text NVARCHAR(150), 
    @CurrencyCode NVARCHAR(50),
    @DisplayLocale NVARCHAR(50),
    @Description NVARCHAR(500),
    @IsActive BIT,
    @UpdatedBy NVARCHAR(256),
    @Culture NVARCHAR(256)

AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.Lists
        SET 
            [Value] = @Value,
            [Text] = @Text,         
            [CurrencyCode]=@CurrencyCode,
            [DisplayLocale]=@DisplayLocale,
            [Description] = @Description,
            [IsActive]=@IsActive,
            [UpdatedBy] = @UpdatedBy,   
            [UpdatedOn] = GETDATE()
        WHERE   [EntryID] = @EntryID AND Culture=@Culture
END
' 
----Other Procedure
```

I search but I am not able to find any clue.Any idea about this error.Thanks.

Comment: line 2 - open single quote, try copying & running from CREATE to END

Comment: @viperguynaz line two single quote generate by `SQLAzureMW v3.9.9.1 Release Binary`.It is lie between all procedure and before this proc there are so many `sp` with `'` its work fine for other proc so why this gives a error that's a main question ? :( .Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ListEntryUpdate]

    @EntryID INT, 
    @Value NVARCHAR(100), 
    @Text NVARCHAR(150), 
    @CurrencyCode NVARCHAR(50),
    @DisplayLocale NVARCHAR(50),
    @Description NVARCHAR(500),
    @IsActive BIT,
    @UpdatedBy NVARCHAR(256),
    @Culture NVARCHAR(256)

AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.Lists
        SET 
            [Value] = @Value,
            [Text] = @Text,         
            [CurrencyCode]=@CurrencyCode,
            [DisplayLocale]=@DisplayLocale,
            [Description] = @Description,
            [IsActive]=@IsActive,
            [UpdatedBy] = @UpdatedBy,   
            [UpdatedOn] = GETDATE()
        WHERE   [EntryID] = @EntryID AND Culture=@Culture
END
```

Comment: where is a solution? `ALTER` bcz its generate from `Mssql` which is run in local pc .

Comment: have you tried to run the basic script without all the extraneous generation stuff?